# Can Nagios send alerts for a critical situation taking place over a prolonged period of time?

Tags: nagios

Is there any plugin or facility in nagios which can do this??
for ex:
the CPU load rises to 80% for 2seconds would not be a problem. I want to get an alert if it remains at 80%++ for at least 5mins.
is it possible??

Comment: That's pretty much the whole point of Nagios.

Answer (score 4):

While a service is okay, Nagios checks the service every `check_interval` minutes (well, technically `interval_length`, but that's usually one minute).  When a service check fails, Nagios will start checking the service every `retry_interval` minutes and will only send an alert if the service remains in the failed state for `max_check_attempts` checks.  See [the documentation](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#service) for details on all of this.

With that in mind, you can either make `retry_interval` large, or set `max_check_attempts` large, or both to increase the time a service must be in a failed state before reporting an error.

So if you want an alert only after a service has failed for more than five minutes, you can set `retry_interval` to 1 and `max_check_attempts` to 5.  Note that the defaults are (I think) `retry_interval` = 1 and `max_check_attempts` = 3.

Comment: If I want to get alert in one/two second(s) I mean real time notification, What should I do???

Answer (score 1):

you can always script your own check. for instance you can have [sar](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/) running on the cron and your custom nagios check control the last 30 minutes of samples from sar.